# Log4Net for web service

Tags: log4net-appender

Log4Net is safe for web applications, because i know log4net is thread safe but its not a process safe. In this scenario we can't use a single file to write a log. Is there is any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are utilising a file appender, then it is true that the DEFAULT behaviour would not be process-safe as you put it. However there are two other options.

From the Log4Net doco:

The FileAppender supports pluggable file locking models via the LockingModel property. The default behavior, implemented by FileAppender.ExclusiveLock is to obtain an exclusive write lock on the file until this appender is closed. The alternative models only hold a write lock while the appender is writing a logging event (FileAppender.MinimalLock) or synchronize by using a named system wide Mutex (FileAppender.InterProcessLock).

Config line would be like:

```
<lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
```

I would presume that exclusive is the most performant.

Although you haven't asked this, you could set the file / path programatically using this syntax in the config:

```
<file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="%property{LogName}" />
```

Then set LogName vi C# in your setup with:

```
log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["LogName"] = fullPathToLogfile + afileName ; 
var configInfo = new FileInfo("configfilename.config");    
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(configInfo);
```